# Assistance needed on the following error: "Invalid Next Control Variable Reference"

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently writing code in VBA which will pull information from Oddschecker. Having inspected the relevant site, I can see the following:

```
<table class = "eventTable"....>

    <tbody id ="t1"....>

         <tr data-bname="Competitor A", data-hcap-sort="1"
```

I am trying to capture Competitor A's name, as well as their ranking (as displayed under data-hcap-sort).

However, I am encountering the following error message:

**Runtime error 13.Type Mismatch**

I'm not sure if I am using the incorrect tags/variables, or, whether there is something basic I am overlooking.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLHCap As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementById("t1")

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
        Debug.Print HTMLTables

    For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTables.getElementsByTagName("data-bname")
        Debug.Print HTMLRow.innerText
    Next HTMLRow

    For Each HTMLHCap In HTMLTables.getElementsByTagName("data-hcap-sort")
        Debug.Print HTMLHCap.innerText
    Next HTMLHCap

 End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance in advance. A novice with VBA, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Well you can't do `For Each HTMLTables... Next HTMLTable` (note the extraneous `s`)

Comment: With your latest edit, I think you got rid of the `Next HTMLTable` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The "Next Control Variable" is `foo` in this example:

```
For Each foo In bar
Next foo
```

When you specify an identifier after `Next` (it's optional), it **must** match exactly with the loop control variable's identifier.

```
For Each foo In Bar
Next zoo '<~ illegal
```

Just remove them all:

```
For Each foo In Bar
Next
```

As for the type mismatch error, I suspect it's this line:

```
Debug.Print HTMLTables
```

Trying to print/output an array will throw a *type mismatch* error 13 like you're getting. Looks like you mean that to be:

```
Debug.Print HTMLTable
```

...although, looking at your post's [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56281084/revisions), I'm not sure what your actual code is anymore.